# python logging module output not working in multiprocessing process

Tags: python, python-logging

I can't get logging to work correctly until I initialize logging for a second time in my python module. There is no output (printing works fine), and if I manage to get output it is not applying the formatting I specified with

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
```

I've tried adding test log entries in my `__init__` which display as expected. However, I cannot log anywhere else in my class. After trying different locations for my test entries and log init, I can log in my `__init__` but not any method afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

On a whim I tried moving initialization from `__init__` to the `run` method specified in my calling parents `mp.Process()` command which worked.

```
self._application = Application(self.outgoing_queue, self.incoming_queue, self.username, application_cores, log_level=logging.DEBUG)
self._application_process = mp.Process(target=self._application.run)
self._application_process.start()
```

My conclusion is that when the class object is handed off to `mp.Process` the `self.log` variable seems to either get clobbered or needs a "fresh" handle in the new process.

Since moving the log initialization to take place after the new process is spawned, all logging is working as expected.